# Proper use of answer vs comment?

Tags: discussion

Referring to the post *[How to trigger 'Quick.setAutoScale(false)' multiTimes with Quick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105157/how-to-trigger-quick-setautoscalefalse-multitimes-with-quick-js)* (Quick.js question):

It's difficult to explain but: I wanted to respond to a comment. But my answer was longer than the allowable length. So I edited the answer into the original question. But it looks confusing to me, because the question is now all merged together. And it looks like all one question and not like it is, a question and a response.

Please, what's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: You know that you can post more than one comment? If you *really* need to write a comment longer than 500 characters just split it into two comments.

Answer (score 18):

What you should have done here was to edit your response into the question more as a form of *"I have tried this, and this is the result of it."* Editing clarifying information and other things you have tried into your question is a *good thing!* It helps make your question easier to answer. The hard part of it is editing the information in so that it all reads as a coherent question, which appears to be the issue you have here.

Comments are good for quick clarification questions and the like. Generally, if someone asks a clarifying question or suggests something you've already tried, you shouldn't reply in the comments and should instead edit your question with the information. This way, potential answerers won't need to read the comments to have all the information necessary to answer the question.

Your title asks about answers as well, so let me touch on that: Answers are for *solutions* to the question. Answers don't have to be *correct* to be posted, but they are extremely likely to be downvoted if they are incorrect. You should not use the "Answer" section of *any* question to reply to a comment or to ask a clarifying question of your own. Only comments should be used for that purpose. At 50 reputation, you'll unlock the ability to comment on posts other than your own.

In this case, you ended up using the correct *method* to respond to the comment (editing your question) while not *quite* having the best approach to that method. If you can, try rephrasing your last edit to the question in such a way that the comment you replied to doesn't have to be involved at all. This will make your question more coherent and easier to read.